# Windows 10 - Hides RDP (Pulse secure terminal) session when minimized

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

8 out of 10 times when I minimize the full screen RDP, it hides or goes background. I then have to open Task manager, Expand Pulse secure Terminal, then double click on the RDP.

[image]

Its not under system tray either.

Sometimes when I expand Pulse Secure Terminal, the RDP would be just white..no icon and can't double click, if I do it collapses the PST. So then my only option is to End that process and start a new session again. This happens only on Windows 10. I wish I could test a direct RDP to some machine to see if this happens, but I don't have any host to test.

Is this happening to anyone else?

Comment: This is happening to me, it is very stupid, it only happens when it is full screen, and you cannot alt-tab it.

in the task manager you can right-click on the item and "bring to front" and that works fine. But I would REALLY like to know a fix for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to a bug from Microsoft. Pulse Secure is aware about this issue and is already working with Microsoft to fix this.

Good news is that the issue has been identified and the fix will be available soon.

In the meantime workaround you mentioned above i.e. launching the session again vie task manager can be used.

Comment: Hi Test, welcome to SuperUser. Please could you provide sources for the statements. "Pulse Secure is aware about this issue and is already working with Microsoft to fix this." and  "Good news is that the issue has been identified and the fix will be available soon."

Answer (score 0):

6.5 years later (Dec 2023), same bug is still here but for the Pulse Secure Client App on Windows 10.
Every single time a connection request is made, the credentials window gets hidden offscreen without the usual possibility to move an offscreen window (Alt-Spacebar, M /S and arrow keys). Only above stated workaround for RDP, via Task Manager , saves the day.
When is this going to be addressed?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1229819)